# thumbnail does not open the image in Mozilla and google chrome

Tags: asp.net, image, thumbnails

Hello everyone I hope I get a reply to this question...I have grid view and one of the fields in e table is a template field with a hyperlink and this hyperlink is basically a thumbnail image...when the user clicks on this thumbnail image the full image opens up in another window. This works fine forme in IE but when I open up the site in mozilla or chrome...I don't get the full image...I get some random numbers and alphabet...so not sure why this is happening only in Mozilla and chrome...Is there any additional line of codes that I need to add for these 2 browsers. Can anyone suggest an idea or a piece of code that wld help me in resolving the issue?.thank u once again everyone and hope to see someone help me out of this...if anything else let me know...thank u

Comment: Suggest you to post the relevant code (markup for thumbnails/hyperlink and the code that serve actual images).

Comment: @VinayC : The code is given below as an answer...I hope it should clear some stuff for u and u will be able to help me out...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its appears from your code that you are not setting the content type for the response. In absense of content type, browsers may treat it as generic binary content, hence the issue. The issue would have been applicable for thumbnail but in that case, you have set it as source to image - hence browser knows that the binary data is in some image format. Browsers such as google chrome issues warning in such cases saying that the data is binary but it is inferring it as image.

The solution is simple - set the content type explicitly:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

You may also consider setting content disposition in case of full images such as

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

From performance perspective, you should consider un-buffered response while sending images. Further, you can also have jpeg file on disk and transfer it directly such as

```
...
    Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
}
```

In such case, ASP.NET runtime handles file transfer to IIS which knows how to stream files to client.

In case of thumbnails, you should consider caching of generated thumbnails to avoid re-generating them again and again.

Comment: I tried the suggestions u gave above but none helps....I dont know whats going wrong....Its the problem in Mozilla and Chrome both of them...

Comment: That helped actually...I tried putting it in a different place and it helped....Thanks a lot VinayC